# Neural Network for Tests Engine

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, game-engine

I'm developing a personality test engine to analyse the personalities of people. When i'm designing the engine which is responsible for calculating the result I was thinking of implementing a neural network or simple accumulative sum of the answers. Each answer will have a percent of accuracy which will affect the final results.

My answer is which solution will give me the accurate results and better in building the engine. I'm very beginner in neural network and I need your help.

Thanks!

Comment: You should write more about your problem. Do you have any data? How it looks like? What books about machine learning have you read? Have you attend to any course of machine learning?

Comment: The data I have is: questions, answers, and the correctness percent of each answer. I have attended a data mining course. We took some neural networks examples like letters recognition. Is it enough?

Comment: For me it was very helpfull to attend to "machine learning" course on Coursera by Andrew Ng - he explains many important issues. Second thing which helps me was book about python and machine learning, with real life examples - text classification, image recognition and classifiing sound.